# Metadata - permission set documents xml missing

Tags: metadata-api

The metadata xml of my permission set in force.com IDE is missing CRED permissions related to the documents object. I have included documents as a part of the force.com project, yet I do not see any of the document's metadata in the permission set xml. The tabsetting part of the documents tab(which is enabled) is also missing from the permission set xml. Any thoughts on how to include the metadata of documents on the permission sets?

PS: The documents have been CRED enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this problem you should retrieve Document metadata type with permission set.

Permission Set only retrieve permission attributes for Metadata types only which are requested with it. It is a default behavior.

Comment: The document metadata is already a part of my eclipse project. We do not have documents as an object separately. Thanks

Comment: @Stygon Did you try to create new Force.com project and select Document and Permission set together to retrieve.

Comment: Did that. Still the document metadata part is missing from the permission set xml.